# php, mysql - folder/file organization for document management

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems

I was wondering what would be the good way to organize documents in a filesystem for my php/mysql application. All info of the docs are stored in a db i am curious about filesystem organization. Is this good way to do it? Is there a better way?

Main folder

```
/documents
```

One folder per client

```
/documents/client1
```

Documents are uploaded here per client

```
/documents/client1/queue
```

After users fill the form docs are saved to a database and moved in this folder

```
/documents/client1/docs
```

Original and filesystem names of the document are stored in a database and filesystem name is something like md5($time.$filename.$client_id) and the document path looks like this

```
/documents/client1/docs/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf
```

I need (minimum) first page of pdf for the thumb and auto barcode reading from the first page

```
/documents/client1/docs/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a-0.gif
```

I also have

```
/documents/client1/scan
```

where files from the scanner goes so users can import them in the database and after that they are renamed and moved to:
/documents/client1/docs

I wonder if i should put files for specific date in a date folder like this:

```
/documents/client1/docs/20110915/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf
```

Or should i use completely different folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using only one common folder for temporary (uploaded) files ? It could make maintenance routine easier (for example deleting all old files).

> I wonder if i should put files for specific date in a date folder like
>   this:
>
> /documents/client1/docs/20110915/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf

If the date is handled by your database it's needless. Nevertheless if for some reason you need to access this file manually (not using your interface) it could be helpful...

Last but not least be aware of your filesystem's limitation. On some filesytem/os you could have a limitation on the number of file per folder (huge but still).

Comment: i was thinking about filesystem limitation. If not the whole date i think i should definitley use a at least a year folder like this: /documents/client1/docs/2011/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf For now i use CentOS 5.5 and ubuntu but i am not shure what is a max files per folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefere a structure that hash the file organisation according to the file name.

```
/documents/6/f/9/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf
```

This will keep good file access and its easy to make the structure deeper if needed.

The problem with using the date as a directory, is that the file location is dependant on some information that may change (we never know!)

Comment: the problem with this is if my client1 wants all their files and databse on their server/cd or whatever. it could be difficult to get only files for client1, but i like your idea :) i am considering something like this: /documents/client_id/documents/6/f/9/6f99caa11e78697612d8f1b4481cd76a.pdf